# Should be the baseline included in MMRM? MMRM vs. cLDA

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, ancova, generalized-estimating-equations

In the cLDA (constrained longitudinal analysis) analysis the baseline value is already taken as a response, so it doesn't have to be included on the right side of the model.

But in MMRM ANCOVA (mixed-model for repeated measures; not a mixed model - it's just generalized least square) it's common to adjust the values (either raw or change from baseline) for the baseline on the right side. But should be then the baseline included in the response variable? If not, then how otherwise calculate contrasts vs. baseline (without doing it via modelling change)?

Comment: Can you please give the full names for the acronyms?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have change from baseline in the response variable, and you can still have baseline as a covariate in the MMRM.
Does that help?